# how to write multi language code for dropdown list in spinner

Tags: android, string, drop-down-menu, spinner, multilingual

I want to write this soil name in local language but in database it should in English.
Normally for string name it works but for dropdown list what to do ?
please ,tell me solution..

Choose a Soil_Type

```
<string-array name="soiltype_arrays">
    <item>Select Item</item>
    <item>Alluvial</item>
    <item>Black</item>
    <item>Laterites Lateritic</item>
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Forest Hill</item>
    <item>Peaty and Marshy</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way by placing the string arrays in the different language folders
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html